# How to schedule build time for jenkins at 8:15 pm with hash code format?

Tags: jenkins

To set the build time for 8:15pm what should be the format?

Is H(15) 20 * * *  correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
15 20 * * *
```

> H - Spread load evenly.

Answer (score 0):

As Avihoo pointed out, you should specify `15` for the minute, rather than trying to use the hash symbol.

Note that `15 20 * * *` will schedule your job for 8:15pm every day of the year, assuming it's not disabled.

You may alternately want to try `15 20 * * 1-5` to run at 8:15 every weekday.

Here's a great reference for Cron formatting with lots of useful examples: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm